# Track data for my own action dimension in Matomo (without custom dimensions plugin)

Tags: plugins, matomo, web-analytics

I need to track some user activity like special clicks, scrolls, and mouse drags, combined with the data I get from the website's back-end.

At first I did it using custom events and created a plugin to read them and generate the reports. But events have their own limitations (like number of archived table rows, ...) and did not fit my use case. Besides events get shown on other reports and views and I don't want to clutter them by my too many events which do not have any meaning out of my plugin's reports.

Using the custom dimensions plugin would not work for me. It is limited and I want to develop and publish my own plugin to my customers.

So I created my own action dimensions.

My plugin works well with the action dimensions I added, and can receive the data from user's activity if I use my previous custom events to send the data. But I don't know how to send my tracking data to it without using events.

I searched for it in Matomo forum, just found some similar questions beening unanswered for a long time.

So my main question is: 
**How I can send the data of user actions to my plugin's dimension without using events?**

Also, am I on the right track? Is creating my own action dimension the correct way to do it?